# Does previous state need to be passed when updating state in functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

The React docs say you need to use an arrow function to pass the previous state in class components (due to asynchronous handling), but does not mention this for functional components. Does this mean that it's fine to use previous state directly when updating state in function components?

Here are the relevant portions of the docs:

[Class components](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> For example, this code may fail to update the counter:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

[Functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
 1:  import React, { useState } from 'react';
 2:
 3:  function Example() {
 4:    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 5:
 6:    return (
 7:      <div>
 8:        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
 9:        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
10:         Click me
11:        </button>
12:      </div>
13:    );
14:  }
```

> Line 9: When the user clicks, we call setCount with a new value. React will then re-render the Example component, passing the new count value to it.

Comment: Yes! In functional components you can use the state value directly, no need to use the arrow function to get the current state, although of course, nothing forbid you from using the arrow function, but it's the same, in almost every situation

Comment: Thank you. So what is the point in the arrow function? And is there anywhere this is documented?

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá That's not true. You should **always** use an arrow function if your state update depends on the previous state. This will become even more important to do once you migrate over to react 18.

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá - arrow functions in useState implementation allow to update array entries/object properties based on previous state. Arrow functions must be used when attaching event handlers, so they can fire on specified event instead of at mounting time.